# Разбиение массива NumPy по разделителю

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть массив NumPy:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4,100, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Как можно его разделить на 3 массива по разделителю 100, чтобы получилось: `[1,2,3,4]`, `[5,6,7,8]`, `[9,10,11,12]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [numpy.split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
In [67]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4,100, 5, 6, 7, 8, 100, 9, 10, 11, 12])

In [68]: idx = np.where(a == 100)[0]

In [69]: idx
Out[69]: array([4, 9], dtype=int64)

In [70]: np.split(a[a != 100], idx - np.arange(len(idx)))
Out[70]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11, 12])]
```

Другой исходный массив (в нем больше элементов == `100`):

```
In [71]: a = np.array([1,2,100,3,4,100,5,6,100,7,100,8,9,10])

In [72]: idx = np.where(a == 100)[0]

In [73]: np.split(a[a != 100], idx - np.arange(len(idx)))
Out[73]: [array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6]), array([7]), array([ 8,  9, 10])]
```

Comment: @Alex, всегда рад помочь! Второй вариант отличается только исходным массивом - решение тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Если с массивом NumPy можно обращаться, как с обычным List'ом, то
можно использовать list.index(100,начинать поиск с какого элемента).
Результат - что-то типа

```
def seekall(whattoseek,somelist):
    res=[]
    initidx=-1
    while True:
     try:
        initidx=somelist.index(whattoseek,initidx+1)
        res+=[initidx]
     except:
        break
    return res

def splitlistby(spltt,lst):
    res=[]
    splttrs=seekall(spltt,lst)
    initidx=0
    for s in splttrs:
      res+=[lst[initidx:s]]
      initidx=s+1
    if initidx<len(lst):
      res+=[lst[initidx:]]
    return res
```

Соответственно, splitlistby вернет искомый "список списков"